# Delphi FireDac Fetching BLOBs

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

I'm using FireBird 2.5, Delphi XE3 and FireDAC components to access data from DB. Database is set to UTF8 charset. Because of maximum row size limitation 64kb in FirebBird 2.5 I'm using for some "additional information" fields type BLOB with subtype TEXT. BLOB fields slows down very much fetching data and this is clear for me and thats why in big detailed reviews i'm trying to show data faster / without blobs.

The problem is with **FireDAC Query** and **FetchOptions->Items** without **[fiBlobs]**. Removing [fiBlobs] from fetching items removes data also from all StringFields which size > 250 chars.

Blob fields are declared as TADWideMemoField, Varchar fields are TADStringField, so why FireDac treats StringField (i.e. VARCHAR(300)) as BLOB and how to avoid this problem? How to fetch data with all varchar fields ?

Comment: Try to set FormatOptions.MaxStringSize to a higher value.

Comment: Thank U for reposne, ADQuery FormatOptions.MaxStringSize is set by default to 32767, changing this property doesn't solve problem with fetching data for TADWideStringFields with size > 1000 without fiBlobs set.

Answer (score 0):

Set this property on connection or query (it has precedence) object:

```
FormatOptions.InlineDataSize := MAXINT;
```

I tested on FireDAC ver. 7.0.1.